# Choosing the most colorful color in javascript

Tags: javascript, colors

I have a group of colors and I want to find their relative [colorfulness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorfulness). Could anyone show me an example in javascript? Many thanks!

Comment: Do you know the equation for colorfulness based on the R, G, B values of the color?

Comment: I would assume the equation for colorfulness is something like x = min(R, G, B); colorfulness = (R - x + G - x + B - x) / 2.0.  But what is colorfulness useful for?  I can see Saturation or Chroma.

Comment: @Šime, Do you answer all questions with a question? @Tamus, thanks I'll try that. Colorfulness is useful if you want to avoid grey colors in a palette.

Comment: @Bodyscanner It's called commenting. It's used to find out more about the question and generally communicate with the OP without having to answer the question. Once you'll figure out how this works, you'll love it :)

Comment: @Šime, No I don't know the answer to the question I posted.

Comment: @Bodyscanner Then your question is "How to calculate colorfulness?". This is an off topic question on this forum, it's not related to any programming language.

Comment: It's related to javascript as that is what the algorithm needs implemented in.  And if it wasn't for @Šime initial question, I wouldn't have known to look at the wiki to realize that calculating colorfulness isn't mentioned. @Kennebec's, your answer is excellent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

// You can compare colors by their saturation and brightness-

```
function rgbtoHsv(rgb){
    var c= rgb.match(/\d+/g),
    r= c[0]/255, g= c[1]/255, b= c[2]/255,
    max= Math.max(r, g, b), min= Math.min(r, g, b),
    h= 0, s= 0, v= max;
    if(max!= min){
        var d= max-min;
        s= d/max;
        switch(max){
            case r: h= (g-b)/d +(g< b? 6: 0);
            break;
            case g: h= (b-r)/d + 2;
            break;
            case b: h= (r-g)/d + 4;
            break;
        }
    }
    return [Math.round(h*60), Math.round(s*100), Math.round(v*100)];
}
function sortColors(a, b){
    var a1= rgbtoHsv(a), b1= rgbtoHsv(b);
    return  (b1[1]+b1[2])-  (a1[1]+a1[2]);
}
```

**var colors=['rgb(255,0,0)','rgb(150,150,150)','rgb(0,200,100)','rgb(0,255,255)'];**
//
**colors.sort(sortColors).join('\n')**

```
/*  returned value: (most to least 'colorful')
rgb(255,0,0)
rgb(0,255,255)
rgb(0,200,100)
rgb(150,150,150)
*/
```

Comment: Fantastic! the combination of both brightness & saturation is what I was after. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

This function returns the saturation (from 0.0 to 1.0) given the RGB values:

```
 function saturation(r,g,b) {
     var minVal = Math.min(r, g, b);
     var maxVal = Math.max(r, g, b);
     var delta = maxVal - minVal;
     if (maxVal === 0 ) {
          return 0;
     } else {
          return (delta / maxVal);
     }
 }
```

I know you asked for colorfulness, but this could be a good stating point.
(I actually didn't knew the difference, thanks for pointing out that wikipedia page)

Comment: Also, you don't need that if statement. If delta is zero, then delta/maxVal will be zero.

Comment: This should be fine: `var max = ...; var min = ...; return (max - min) / max;`

Comment: Right, but interestingly jslint on http://jsfiddle.net/ didn't point out any issue (about the declaration).

Comment: Ok, now the check is to prevent division by zero (that is bad, they say)

Comment: @UVL When you forget to declare a variable, then that variable becomes an implicit global variable. This is not an error. However, it should be avoided.

Comment: @UVL Yes, you have to check maxVal, not delta. Consider this: `return maxVal ? (max - min) / max : 0;`

Comment: Many thanks UVL! One further note, if I wanted to avoid dark shades (eg a color with high saturation but a very high or low HSV.value - diagram here- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV, which to my mind is not very 'colourful'), could I sort by saturation then by HSV.value? I was curious if there's some formula which takes into account both saturation & value.